# PKPassLibrary not returning passes

Tags: swift, swift5, applepay, wallet

I have added Debit Card programmatically to Apple Wallet using swift code.
I need to show card status as provisioned so that user can should not try to add this card again.

for that I am using below code to get passes from wallet

```
        let passLibrary = PKPassLibrary()
        let devicePaymentPasses = passLibrary.passes().compactMap { $0.paymentPass }
        let remotePaymentPasses = passLibrary.remotePaymentPasses()
```

both devicePaymentPasses and remotePaymentPasses are empty. please help.

Comment: Does your app have permission to access the payment pass?  Is the pass signed with a certificate issued from the same team as your app?

Comment: It's Payment Pass, I am adding debit card. I have added to wallet successfully programatically without having .pkpass.  I have entitlement with Pass Type IDs and com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning. Can you explain what do u mean by app having permission to access the payment pass ? what do u have to do? I assume that the pass which I have added to wallet from my app, PKPassLibrary should be able to give me the list of those pass.

Comment: @KhageshPatel I am struggling with the same situation, did you get a solution for this?

Comment: @Ash_B yes. but I don’t have answer as fix is at server side team. Basically for sandbox testing server team needs to some kind of setup while communicating to Apple server. I will try to find more detail from my server team. It’s better to test in production environment once your app is live.

Comment: @KhageshPatel, I've been testing on production using TestFlight however the PKPassLibrary still return zero passes both for local and remote payment passes. It would be really helpful if you could share some more about the server setup. Thanks

Comment: Did you get a solution here? I have the same issue.

Comment: Do you have a solution? I can see my passes but if I put one of them to removePass() nothing happened

Comment: @KhageshPatel: Have you find any solution for pass access from wallet ?

Comment: Has anyone found any solution to this? 
I'm adding a secure element pass with a PKShareableConfiguration. The pass is added successfully. I want to check wether the pass is already in the wallet to skip showing the "Add to Wallet" button but the `PKPAssLibrary().passes()` returns always an empty array despite the card being in the wallet. I tried the above suggestion without success.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the *Wallet* entitlement to the app, in order to read passes created with the app's team ID.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out.

Comment: its not working same result no cards in PKPassLibrary()